# How to apply google oauth on kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, oauth, oauth-2.0, kibana

I need to apply google oauth on kibana for security purpose.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add more details what you have tried so far? Please also take a moment to look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to write a plugin for Kibana, [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/user-impersonation-with-x-pack-integrating-third-party-auth-with-kibana) goes in some details on how to accomplish that, the catch with this approach is that you'll need x-pack(which is a paid product) to accomplish that as described there, but it's also possible to write a plugin without x-pack anyway, just some extra work.

Other option, where you won't need x-pack would be to have a reverse proxy in front of your kibana where you can implement the oauth and you could configure that kibana only accepts requests from that rev-proxy.